# How can I make my checkbox not uncheck when clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I have a checkbox, well actually multiple checkboxes, but I just want for one checkbox to be able to set it on and off. But the catch is I have a POST sending a PHP variable to decide if the box is checked on load. But the method I have used, wont allow me to uncheck the box as `IF $VAR="YES" CHECKBOX = CHECKED` so my JScript will not uncheck it.

I am not sure if my explanation reveals the problem so I'm hoping the code will do.

If anyone can see a simple way around this i'd be grateful. I just want a checkbox that is checked if the POST is sent and not checked when I click it.

Thank you.

```php
<input type="checkbox" id="withvideo" name="withvideo" class='Mcheckbox' value="withvideo"
        <?php if ($hasvideo==='yes'): ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?>
        onclick="chbxhas(this); <?php $hasvideo==='yes'; ?>">
</input>

<label for="withvideo" class="checkboxes" title='Show Items With Videos'>With Video</label><i class="fa fa-video plusclass" ></i>

<---receiving page--->

if (isset($_POST['withvideo'])){$hasvideo="yes";}

else {$hasvideo="no";}

<---jscript--->
<script>
function chbxhas(objhas)
{
    var that = objhas;
    (objhas);

    if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked === true) {
        document.getElementById('withvideo').checked = false;
    }

    document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: why did you check param before you take ???

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementById("withvideo").disabled = true;
```

instead of

```
 document.getElementById("withvideo").checked = true;
```

Comment: iv tried that already, it seems the php variable is continuously checking it so the jscript is useless..